How to create dynamic steps in Spring Batch?
I have the following MigrationService and BatchoCnfig classes and want to pass jobParameters to the related steps using MigrationJobListener shown below. However, I am getting "Could not autowire. No beans of 'String' type found." error it the constructor of the steps on the parameter lines (String collectionName, String query). How to fix it?
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MigrationService {

    private final BatchJobLauncher batchJobLauncher;

    public void runJob(UsageDataRequest request) {

        // Define your collection-query pairs
        Map<String, String> pairs = new HashMap<>();
        pairs.put("employee", "{}");
        pairs.put("student", "{}");

        // Convert to JSON string
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonPairs = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(pairs);

        // Set JobParameters with properly encoded JSON string
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("collectionsAndQueries", jsonPairs)
                .toJobParameters();

        batchJobLauncher.launchJob(jobParameters);
    }
}


@Configuration
public class BatchConfig {

    @Bean
    public Job migrationJob(JobRepository jobRepository,
                            @Qualifier("sourceTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager sourceTransactionManager,
                            @Qualifier("sourceMongoTemplate") MongoTemplate sourceMongoTemplate,
                            @Qualifier("targetMongoTemplate") MongoTemplate targetMongoTemplate,
                            @Qualifier("dataDeletionTasklet") DataDeletionTasklet dataDeletionTasklet,
                            @Qualifier("migrationJobListener") MigrationJobListener migrationJobListener) {

        // access job parameters via migrationJobListener
        Map<String, String> jobParametersMap = migrationJobListener.getJobParametersMap();

        JobBuilder jobBuilder = new JobBuilder("migrationJob", jobRepository).incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer());
        SimpleJobBuilder simpleJobBuilder = new SimpleJobBuilder(jobBuilder);

        // iterate over jobParametersMap to create and chain the steps dynamically
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : jobParametersMap.entrySet()) {
            String collectionName = entry.getKey();
            String query = entry.getValue();

            // pass collectionName - query pairs to the related steps
            Step deleteStep = deleteMatchingData(jobRepository, sourceTransactionManager, dataDeletionTasklet, collectionName, query);
            Step insertStep = insertData(jobRepository, sourceTransactionManager, sourceMongoTemplate, targetMongoTemplate, collectionName, query);

            simpleJobBuilder = simpleJobBuilder.start(deleteStep).next(insertStep);
        }

        return simpleJobBuilder
                .listener(migrationJobListener)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step deleteData(JobRepository jobRepository,
                                   PlatformTransactionManager sourceTransactionManager,
                                   DeletionTasklet deletionTasklet,
                                   String collectionName,
                                   String query
    ) {
        // configure the tasklet with the collectionName and query
        deletionTasklet.setCollectionName(collectionName);
        deletionTasklet.setQuery(query);

        return new StepBuilder("deleteData", jobRepository)
                .tasklet(deletionTasklet, sourceTransactionManager)
                .listener(new MigrationStepListener("deleteData"))
                .build();
    }
}


DeletionTasklet:
@Component
public class DeletionTasklet implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String query;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String collectionName;

    // code omitted

    // here I try to access these parameters passed from BatchConfig

}


MigrationJobListener:
@Component
public class MigrationJobListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    private Map<String, String> jobParametersMap;

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        JobParameters jobParameters = jobExecution.getJobParameters();
        String jsonPairs = jobParameters.getString("collectionsAndQueries");

        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            jobParametersMap = objectMapper.readValue(jsonPairs, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {});
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to parse job parameters", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

    }

    public Map<String, String> getJobParametersMap() {
        return jobParametersMap;
    }
}


Interesting question +1. Checking to find the solution for it.

@AnishB. Thanks, I think it would be used in many scenarios when we need something generic based on the request parameters. As I don't have many collections to migrate, for now probably not needed to use paralel processing. But in any case, I think it would be worthy to make such implementation by building steps dynamically.

Ok. I see. I'm looking for generic solution only if I find something.

Internally, JobBuilder is doing the same as what was mentioned by Mahmoud. So, I guess you have to do the same as directed by him.

Is there any issue in taking that path? If yes, then what issue are you facing?

@AnishB See my update please.

I saw your updated question. Now, where is the issue?

Passing the key-value pairs from Service and accessing them in migrationJob method. I am passing some jobParameters from service like this >>> `

Map<String, String> pairs = new HashMap<>();
pairs.put("employees", "{}");
pairs.put("students", "{}");

// Convert to JSON string
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonPairs = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(pairs);

// Set JobParameters with properly encoded JSON string
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
        .addString("collectionsAndQueries", jsonPairs)
        .toJobParameters();

batchJobLauncher.launchJob(jobParameters);```

Okay. I have got it.

Also got error as I simply apply boxing. See my last update please.

I see that error.

I have added my answer please check.

Go for ExecutionContext. It will be easier. Read this -> https://medium.com/@umutaskin/how-to-pass-data-among-steps-in-a-spring-batch-application-3568ae6f63d6

can you try adding this field in migrationJob  class @Value("#{jobParameters}") Map<String, Object> jobParameters to see if it works

I tried but generally get autowire related errors. At the last stage, created a JobExecutionListener and passed parameters to the job. However, when passing thee pairs to the steps, encountering "Could not autowire. No beans of 'String' type found." errors. If you have any suggestion on top of this approach or another way, feel free to let me know.

Can you update the question to add the error that you are facing?

Sure, I updated with the latest situation. Could you have a look at please?

Do you have a codebase to reproduce this? If yes, please share it via github so that i can run it on my local.

Thanks, but for now I needed to skip dynamic build and needed to solve another problem to proceed. Could you please have a look at this?
Writing multiple collections based on related queries in Spring Batch

Could you check it? I made some implementations but they migrated the last chunk of the first collection to the second collection.

Is current question resolved?

Not completely, but can be with some little updates.

Use SimpleJobBuilder class which has more functionalities than JobBuilder itself.
Update code to this:
@Bean
public Job migrationJob(JobRepository jobRepository,
                        @Qualifier("sourceTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager sourceTransactionManager,
                        @Qualifier("sourceMongoTemplate") MongoTemplate sourceMongoTemplate,
                        @Qualifier("targetMongoTemplate") MongoTemplate targetMongoTemplate,
                        @Qualifier("dataDeletionTasklet") DataDeletionTasklet dataDeletionTasklet) {

    // Step[] stepsArray = // create your steps array or pass it as a parameter

    JobBuilder jobBuilder = new JobBuilder("migrationJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer());
    SimpleJobBuilder simpleJobBuilder = new SimpleJobBuilder(jobBuilder);
    for (Step step : stepsArray) {
        simpleJobBuilder = simpleJobBuilder
           .start(deleteMatchingData(jobRepository, sourceTransactionManager, dataDeletionTasklet))
           .next(insertData(jobRepository, sourceTransactionManager, sourceMongoTemplate, targetMongoTemplate));
    }
    
    return simpleJobBuilder.listener(new MigrationJobCompletionListener("migrationJob"))
           .build();
}

This should work. See if this helps.

Thank you so much, it will work. I just need to pass key-value pairs from my Service , but I get some autowire errors. SO, what is the most proper way to pass some pairs to this migrationJob method? I also added a second update that I tried in the service method. Not sure if I should use ExecutionContext or JobParameters for this purpose. Could you check please?

@MuratYıldız Okay. Let me look at it.

I just need to access job parameters in the migrationJob method so that I can iterate each key-value pair and then repeat steps dynamically. For example I have 2 <collection, query> pair as <"employee", "{}> and <"student", "{}>. Then I will process the steps 2 times for these 2 collections. But although I can access job parameters sent from Service in ItemReader and ItemWriters, I cannot get them in migrationJob method. But I need inside that method as I iterate inside it.

@MuratYıldız I have added my comment and article reference.

Thanks, but as far as I see, all the examples are accessing these parameters from tasklets or item reader/writers rather than job methods. Any idea about it?

You might share your comments and I will definitely check and inform you. Thanks in advance.

@MuratYıldız Okay. I need to check on how to get the parameters from job. Is that what you are asking for?

But I definitely need to access these parameters in the job method as I repeat steps in that method, am I wrong?

Let me check I will update you.

yes, how to get these parameters sent from Service and get in migrationJob method. Just need this.

By the way, voted up and waiting for answer to completely fixing the problem ;)

@MuratYıldız I got it. Let me do some research. I will get back to you soon. You have a very complicated requirement. But good to learn these things.

Would flow a better solution for this scenario? I am thinking of moving the loop logic to flow and then manipulate job parameters easily and passing to the steps. What would you think?
